# Switching Kubuntu loading screen to Gnome

Tags: gnome, kubuntu

some time ago I've switched Gnome desktop to Ubuntu.
Now I'd like to switch back to Gnome so I've selected it on loading screen. Desktop session loads correctly in Gnome but every time I restart the OS, I still have Kubuntu loading screen.

Could you advise me where can I set loading screen to Gnome one as well?

Thanks

Comment: Additionally I've noticed that when I run:

printf 'Desktop: %s\nSession: %s\n' "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" "$GDMSESSION"

in the terminal, the following is displayed:

Desktop: ubuntu:GNOME
Session: 

Is this correct? Shouldn't I have Session populated, too?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it turns out that I needed to switch from sddm to gdm3 using:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```